# sending custom values to devise mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've got a multi-tenant app and I'm trying to send some information about the current tenant along with with the devise mailer so I can customize some of the text.

Anyone know how I can send my current_tenant object too? I've seen a few methods where you overwrite the mailer in the User model, but current_tenant is only available in the controller.

```
def create
  self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)
end
```

Ideally, I'd like to do something like

```
def create
  self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params, current_tenant)
end
```

and be able to access my current_tenant object inside the email.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this will be in devise at some point but in the meantime I found a fork that allows for somebody to pass mailer_params into the message.  I tried it and it works. Here's the github discussion in case anyone else is interested:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/2207